# PaaS DNS Synchronization

Tags: dns, openshift, paas

I'm not exactly sure if this is more of a DNS question or the nature of most PaaS's.

I purchased a domain from namecheap.com. I wanted to get a WordPress site up and running so I could start development so I went over to openshift, created an account and installed WordPress, which was very easy! Only one problem... I'm having issues trying to sync my domain name from namecheap with the application on openshift. I must admit I've always purchased the domain name and hosting together so I've never had to go this route so I'm not entirely sure this has anything to do with the fact openshift is a PaaS.

In openshift, I have the URL for my application `applicationname-account.rhcloud.com` and I've added an alias on my namecheap.com account which works for a redirect... If I go to my purchased domain, `www.example.com`, it will simply redirect me to `example-account.rhcloud.com`. But I do not want a redirect...

I guess I'm confused as to how you get a domain name that you've purchased from one company to a hosting company. Do I need to modify something on my namecheap account?

Answer (score 1):

This document states that you need to add a bare CNAME record to your DNS setup (may be what you refer to as an alias)

https://www.openshift.com/blogs/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way

then add an alias to your Openshift application using the `rhc` command line tool, eg:

```
rhc alias add example-account www.example.com
```